# How to get Firebase Dynamic Links to work with App Clips?

Tags: ios, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, apple-appclips

Is Firebase Dynamic Links meant to work with App Clips? If the app isn't installed on iOS I would like the App Clip to popup instead of taking users to the App Store? Is this possible?

Here are the scenarios I would like to have happen:

iOS

1. User does not have the app installed and clicks the link - App Clip opens.
2. User has the app installed and clicks the link - App opens

Android

1. User does not have the app installed and clicks the link - Google Play Store opens.
2. User has the app installed and clicks the link - App opens

Other Platforms

1. Website opens when the link is clicked.

Comment: I am having the same question and cannot find any answer anywhere.
The answer below seems to be talking about other firebase features such as firestore or realtime databse, which indeed do not work in app clip.
But doing the dynamic link redirection to the app clip should be doable right?

Answer (score 1):

gRPC doesn't work with app clips, so unfortunately all of the swift sdk for firebase will not work with app clips. The best workaround so far is to use REST for reading/writing to firebase and, if you need a listener, to use server side events to provide that functionality.